# My output always prints '.' before my expect output. CS50 PSET2

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        printf ("%c", toupper(argv[i][0]));
    }
    printf ("\n");
}
```

Its supposed to take your full name and return your initials. It returns what it is supposed to, except, it always returns a period before my output.

Comment: `int i = 0` --> `int i = 1`

Comment: argv[0] corresponds to the executable name. So, start from 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You print the first character of every element of the `argv` array of strings.  The first element, `argv[0]` is the name of the executable. You probably invoke your executable as `./myprogram`, hence the `.` that is printed first.

You should enumerate `argv` starting at entry number 1. Furthermore, you should cast the `char` as `(unsigned char)` because `toupper()` is only defined for all the values of type `unsigned char` and the special value `EOF`, not the potentially negative values of the `char` type if it is signed by default.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        putchar(toupper((unsigned char)argv[i][0])));
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```